# How to start Tornado periodic callback at a specific time?

Tags: python, tornado

Currently in my Tornado application, I am calling a callback periodically using `PeriodicCallback` every hour. Like this:

```
import tornado.ioloop
from tornado.ioloop import PeriodicCallback

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application(
      handlers=urls,
      template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
      static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
      debug=True
      )
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)

    # Here i have option to specify interval, but how to specify when to start?
    daily_alerts = PeriodicCallback(lambda: send_email.daily_alert(), 3600000)
    daily_alerts.start()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Here, I have the option to set the interval time (`3600000`), but how do I specify when this periodical callback should start?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to control exactly when the callback is scheduled, it's better to use `IOLoop.add_timeout` directly instead of `PeriodicCallback`.

```
def schedule_next_email():
    tomorrow = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    midnight = datetime.combine(tomorrow, datetime.time.min)
    def wrapper():
        send_email.daily_alert()
        schedule_next_email()
    IOLoop.current().add_timeout(midnight, wrapper)

schedule_next_email()  # call at startup to schedule first call
```

Recomputing the interval every time helps you send at the same time every day even when daylight savings time changes and days can have either 23 or 25 hours.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will accept your answer once i test it in sometime.

Answer (score 0):

I found @ben-darnell's solution useful, but it had some issues for me so I wanted to post a working variation where the wrapper and function are split:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
import datetime
import pytz    

def wrapper():
    # Add one day to the current time
    tomorrow = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    # Strip the date from "tomorrow" with the minimum timestamp time.min to get midnight
    midnight = datetime.datetime.combine(tomorrow, datetime.time.min)
    IOLoop.current().add_timeout(datetime.datetime.timestamp(midnight), print_test)

def print_test():
    print('test')
    wrapper()
```