# TypeError: Unsupported deadline datetime.datetime(....)

Tags: python, tornado

I'm trying to run a function periodically using IOLoop in Tornado. However, the following code gets the error?

> TypeError: Unsupported deadline datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 11, 0, 35, 49, 445200)

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
import datetime

def schedule_next_email():
    # t = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)
    t = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)
    # t2 = datetime.datetime.combine(t, datetime.time.min)
    def wrapper():
        print('test')
        schedule_next_email()
    IOLoop.current().add_timeout(t, wrapper)  # Error

schedule_next_email()
```

Ref: [How to start Tornado periodic callback at a specific time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41073194/how-to-start-tornado-periodic-callback-at-a-specific-time)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "", line 8, in schedule_next_email
  File "C:\Users\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 585, in add_timeout
    raise TypeError("Unsupported deadline %r" % deadline)
TypeError: Unsupported deadline datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 11, 0, 47, 28, 944375)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`add_timeout`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_timeout) takes a `timedelta`, not a `datetime`, as the deadline argument, so just pass the `timedelta` directly:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
import datetime

def schedule_next_email():
    t = datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)
    def wrapper():
        print('test')
        schedule_next_email()
    IOLoop.current().add_timeout(t, wrapper)

schedule_next_email()
```

Make sure the IO loop starts in one way or another; I added `IOLoop.current().start()` to the end for testing purposes, though it may be different for production code.

Comment: @ca9163d9 I'm guessing that Tornado made some changes to their API between 2016 and now, which is why the other question's code doesn't work.

Comment: I also updated the answer, which should hopefully resolved your issue.

Comment: Thanks. it works now after adding `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()`.

Comment: BTW, I used the approach from another answer - `IOLoop.current().add_timeout(datetime.datetime.timestamp(t), wrapper)`

Comment: Just wonder if the recursive calls will cause stack overflow if running for long time.

Comment: @ca9163d9 It shouldnt cause a stack overflow, because this isn't a recursive call: wrapper calls schedule_next_email, which setups a callback on the event loop to call wrapper; however, `schedule_next_email` **does not** call wrapper directly.